# CSS Validator doesn't recognize flex-wrap: wrap;

Tags: css, validation, flexbox

I am trying to validate a css file at w3c css validator. When it is tested it returns an error stating that *"Property flex-wrap- doesn't exist : wrap"*. This is my part that css validator sees wrong.

```
.row {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap-: wrap;
}
```

Any suggestion how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flex-wrap-` indeed doesn't exist...but `flex-wrap` exists. See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) on Mozilla Developer Network

Replace your CSS with the following :

```
.row {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```